# Can I verify if two App Scoped Ids belong to the same user in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My application authenticates users through their Facebook accounts. I'm aware that Facebook gives each application a different User Id (App Scoped ID).

But I'm using a service that provides a list of posts for an specific tag, so I have a list of user's ids but they are scoped to that third party service, so that User Id would not match the one my application has obtained.

I really don't need to find the user's "real" ID, and I know this is not possible. But is there a way I can ensure that both App Scoped IDs (from two different applications) refer to the same Facebook user?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook got a solution for this, the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/

Of course this only works with Apps you manage, you cannot map users with Apps you do not own.

Comment: What if I don't own both applications? One of them is from a third party service. Would it be possible then?

Comment: it only works for apps you own, of course. there is no way to match users with apps you do not own.